# Finding and storing row number (int) for specific value in df

Tags: python, pandas

I am using the following code to detect a row number (the header) in multiple CSV files which I am processing:

```
combined_xlsx = pd.read_excel(xlsxfile, nrows=20)
out = np.where([combined_xlsx.values == 'PCA'])[1][0]
combined_xlsx = pd.read_excel(xlsxfile, header=out+1)
combined_xlsx.dropna(subset=['PCA'], inplace=True)
```

Based on the value 'PCA' occurring, the header row is decided and stored and used to read the whole file. I cannot use a fixed number with the header= method because the header row occurs in various rows in the original files.

In case the header row is at row position 0, the code doesn't work and I receive the following error:

```
IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0
```

How can I solve this issue and correctly determine the header row whether at row position 0 or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed with the following function:

```
def headerfinder(df, mystr):
    cols = df.columns.isin([mystr])
    if True in cols:
        out = 0
    else:
        out = np.where([df.values == mystr])[1][0] + 1
    return(out)
```

Not a neat solution, but works in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Your usage of [`np.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) is wrong. It's function signature is `numpy.where(condition, x, y)` where `condition` a boolean list. For `True` value, it yields x, otherwise yield y.